# Sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{2x^2}{x^2+(1-2nx)^2}$, does it have a uniformly converging subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequence-of-function, arzela-ascoli

Let $f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $$ f_n(x)=\frac{2x^2}{x^2+(1-2nx)^2},\ n\in \mathbb{N}. $$ Then does the sequence $(f_n)$ have a subsequnce that converges uniformly on $[0,1]$.

I was trying to apply **The Arzelà-Ascoli Theorem**, but I got the family is not equicontinuous. As if it is equicontinuous then

> $$ \forall \ \varepsilon>0, \exists \ \delta(\varepsilon)>0,\ \text{s.t } \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\ \text{and } \forall x,y\in [0,1], |x-y|< \delta \implies |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<\varepsilon. $$ Take $\varepsilon=1, x=\frac{1}{2n},\ y=\frac{1}{n},$ then $|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|=\frac{2n^2}{n^2+1}\nless 1$.

So, I can not conclude anything. Then how will I say whether the sequence has a uniformly converging subsequence or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not have a uniformly convergence subsequence. We can see that the limit function $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x)=0$. However, for any subsequence $f_{n'}(x)$, 
  \begin{equation}
    \max_{x\in\left[ 0,1 \right]} \left|f_n(x)-0\right|\geq f_{n'}\left( \frac{1}{2n'} \right)=2.
    \label{}
  \end{equation}
  thus, this subsequece is not uniformly convergent.